# IOS blocks AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ios7, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I am using the `AFNetworking` to connect to API in my code. 
Now I have general things on my view controllers like switches and picker views which will determine what is sent to the API. 
So I will need to call the AFNetworking block like this :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:returncompletedURL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

and at the end I use `[operation start]` to run the block, quite easy!

but I need this in some sort of a method/function so that I can call it and pass arguments over to it as and when a switch is changed or a label is changed. Instead of writing the same block over and over again i want it as a function.

I would use `[operation start]` in the function to check if a switch is on/off but it does not see it within the function.

If i wrap a method around the `AFNetworking` block would that bad and I cannot use the RETURN statement within a block.

Generally advice is needed if i have switches and labels and if the user changes any of this then the block needs to be called straight the way to amend the API call.

thanks

Comment: So, basically you want to enclose the block in a method and then call it upon some user action such as change in switch or label. Is this what you meant?

Comment: If I understand well, you seem to just need adding IBOutlets to your view controller referencing all UI controls that have an impact on your URL building process, and when you want to fire your API request, just use these IBOutlet references to catch all required values and build your URL. But maybe your question is about something else?...

Comment: GoGreen thats correct, cos there is a handful of different switches etc effect the API, and within the programming flow the buttons may be pressed after the API has run and therefore it will not be accurate. So if a switch is pressed to 1 or 0 or a drop down box has been changed the API call needs to be run.

Comment: ok. then I suggest you to write the code in some method say "startWebService" for instance, alongwith the `[operation start]` in that method. You may then call this method in response to any user action as you please.

Comment: i thought so, then i can return output to NSUserDefaults or something!

Answer (score 0):

I could do something like this, create a method that can return for you value:

```
 Method that you could insert your request.

 -(void)callRequestWithParameter:(id)parameter returnState:(void(^)(id response))response{
    // here make request 
    // use parameter to send what you want on request
    if (requestSucess){
       response(data for return our status);
    }
};

//Method for handle request and answer 
-(void)requestData:(id)dataParameter {
 [ClassName callRequestWithParameter:@(2) returnState: (id response)^{
      if(response){
        // call some update method like
        [self updateItensWithData:data];
      }
 }
};`
```